# I cannot figure out how to make the edit button work

Tags: javascript, html

This is something I've been working on for a while now, and it's about to be released I just cannot figure out for the life of me on how to make the edit button work. If you can find a way for it to work just leave the java down below and the changes that you've done it would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">Vehicle Management</div>
        <h2>List of your characters' vehicles</h2>
        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
            <thead>
                <th>Vehicle Make</th>
                <th>Vehicle Model</th>
                <th>Vehicle Color</th>
                <th>Vehicle Owner</th>
                <th>License Plate</th>
                <th>Details</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </thead>


            <tr ng-show="vehList.length > 0" class="text-left" ng-repeat="veh in vehList">
                <td>{{veh.vehmake}}</td>
                <td>{{veh.vehmodel}}</td>
                <td>{{veh.vehcolor}}</td>
                <td>{{veh.vehowner}}</td>
                <td>{{veh.vehplate}}</td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.stolen" class="text-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i> Stolen<br /></span>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.registrationExpired" class="text-warning">Expired Registration<br /></span>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.noRegistration" class="text-warning">No Registration<br /></span>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.insuranceExpired" class="text-warning">Expired Insurance<br /></span>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.noInsurance" class="text-warning">No Insurance<br /></span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.active" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-star"><br/></span>
                    <span ng-show="veh.details.nonactive" class="btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"><br/></span>
                    <button ng-click="edit=true" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></button>
                    <button ng-click="deleteVehicle($index)" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></button>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <!-- Only shown when there's no vehicule already created -->
            <tr ng-show="vehList.length == 0">
                <td colspan="7" class="text-center">
                    <h4>No Vehicle Found, Please Create One.</h4>
                </td> 
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7" class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalAdNewVehicle"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class="panel-body">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modalAdNewVehicle" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4>Vehicle Information
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Vehicle Make</span>
                                <input ng-model="newveh.vehmake" autofocus type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Vehicle Model</span>
                                <input ng-model="newveh.vehmodel" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Vehicle Color</span>
                                <input ng-model="newveh.vehcolor" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Vehicle Owner</span>
                                <input ng-model="newveh.vehowner" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Vehicle Plate</span>
                                <input ng-model="newveh.vehplate" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="container-fluid text-left">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click-"!newveh.details.active" ng-model="newveh.details.active" type="checkbox" value"">Active</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click="!newveh.details.nonactive" ng-model="newveh.details.nonactive" type="checkbox" value="">Not Active</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click="!newveh.details.stolen" ng-model="newveh.details.stolen" type="checkbox" value="">Stolen</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click="!newveh.details.registrationExpired" ng-model="newveh.details.registrationExpired" type="checkbox" value="">Expired Registration</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click="!newveh.details.noRegistration" ng-model="newveh.details.noRegistration" type="checkbox" value="">No Registration</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click="!newveh.details.insuranceExpired" ng-model="newveh.details.insuranceExpired" type="checkbox" value="">Expired Insurance</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label><input ng-click="!newveh.details.noInsurance" ng-model="newveh.details.noInsurance" type="checkbox" value="">No Insurance</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer text-center">
                <button ng-click="addNewVehicle()" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(this).find('[autofocus]').focus();
    });
</script>
```

There is java script for everything else to work, i just cannot figure out how to make the edit button work

Comment: *just leave the java down below* - `Java != JavaScript`

Comment: Hey, what do you want to edit with the edit button?

Comment: You're mixing up jQuery and Angular together. Use jQuery OR Angular, NOT both, and your problem will go away. Chances are that this problem comes directly from the fact that you are trying to make two very different things work together.

Comment: you'll need to define what you mean by "working" in the context of the button. And also, what does it do now? Do you get any errors? If so, post them here if you can't figure out how to fix them.